# Build error in Team Foundation Server. (Build Failed)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am getting the following error when I try to Build my solution in TFS 2015 version. Code is working properly in my local computer., but throws an error when I try to build in TFS. [Also here is the screenshot of my tfs build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVpaA.png)
 "***Process completed with exit code -1073741790.***"

[here is my build step log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIz5.png)

Comment: you need to share some logs, at least from the failing task. a screenshot like this does not help to determine what went wrong.

Comment: @D.J              Sir, thank you for your quick response, but sadly the log also says the same error. Anyways, I have attached a copy of logs in my post.

Comment: of course they say the same error ^^ the interessting info is when this occures. during the build or publish of a website or some npm-command that is called during the build etc...

Comment: @D.J I didn't quite understand what you are saying sir. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @PrudhviBharadwaj Just try to enable verbose Debug Mode (set the value of the variable `system.debug` to `true` in you build definition), then check the log of build step and post the log message here for troubleshooting.

Comment: It could be an installation problem on your server. Have you tried to reinstall?